# Change sender domain in Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

the current situation:

I have a server with IIS and Exchange. The intern domain is corp.domain.com and the external domain for our website is domain.com. At the moment I can only send emails from sender.name@corp.domain.com. This often results in a "Verify fails"-answer from other mail servers which should receive our mails.

How can I change this to sender.name@domain.com?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you need to do two things. Number one, on your Exchange server, you need to put your external domain as an '[Accepted Domain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124745.aspx)'. This will allow the Exchange server to accept email destined for that domain.

The second thing you'll need to do is create an [email address policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171.aspx) on the Exchange server that applies the '@external.com' to their email addresses.

These two things, coupled with MX records pointing to the server (and the appropriate holes opened in your firewall) should allow email that is destined for 'external.com' to make its way to your exchange server, be accepted, and forwarded to the correct user.

The mail address that is sent (corp.domain.com) is defined in the address policy I mentioned above. If you modify that, you can allow the external domain to become the default SMTP address.

Comment: John: I guess I assumed that the OP already had the Accepted Domains and E-mail Address policy configured. I probably shouldn't have assumed that. Thanks for a more in depth answer.

Comment: @joeqwerty No worries!! It wasn't really clarified or not, so I just figured I'd cover it. I'd rather write too big of an answer than not enough of one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the Send connector FQDN by which your server identifies itself or are you referring to the From field in the outbound email?

It sounds like you're referring to the From field in the outbound email. If so, configure your E-mail address policy to set the sender.name@domain.com address as the Reply address. This is the address that will be used in the From field in outbound emails.